# Game lag on Android 5.0

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm currently working on a game project on mobile devices.

It runs smoothly on all platforms (iOS, Android 4.x), however for Android 5.0, on some of the devices (Samsung note 4, nexus 5 etc.) it lags very much. Especially on senses with lots of static meshes (I know this will cause bad performance in general but all other devices are fine).

Does anyone have any similar issues on Android 5.0? I currently have no clue that why it happens, is there anything different from 4.x to 5.0 that may cause the problem? Any ideas?

Comment: Please show a reproducable sample.

Comment: Please describe in more detail what you're doing. Using a game engine? OpenGL-ES? Software rendering with Canvas? Have you examined the behavior with systrace?